# SQL Join / WHERE issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been looking but can't find an answer to this so I'm hoping someone can help.  I have two tables

Table 1 (audited items)

```
audit_session_id    asset_number 
Audit1              1      
Audit1              2       
Audit2              3
```

Table 2 (asset)

```
asset_number location<br>
1            15
2            10
3            15
```

What I want is a table of assets that appear in Table 2 but not in Table 1 for a given location and audit_session_id.  What I have is:

```
SELECT a.asset_number 
FROM auditeditems ai 
RIGHT JOIN asset a 
  on ai.asset_number = a.asset_number 
WHERE ai.asset_number IS NULL 
AND a.location_id=15;
```

However I can't filter on audit_session_id as it is NULL. So I get the result:

1,3 when it should just be 1. (assuming I was looking at the audit1 session)

I keep thinking this should be straight forward but can't see where I'm going wrong.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just an observation: In the real world, RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare.

Comment: Many people find left join hard to understand, and even more find right join utterly confusing. So, my advice is to always do left join. It's so much easier to understand `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: I agree with the posters above, if I was doing a code review and saw a right join I'd be failing that code straight away. They're only useful in an extremely limited set of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks everyone so Left Join it is.  So restructuring the query to a LEFT JOIN as per (JohnHC example) then how do I solve the original issue?

Comment: If you want to find `assets that appear in Table 2 but not in Table 1` then those assets will NOT have `audit_session_id` (not in table1). So certainly you CANNOT find any with given `audit_session_id`. May be you misunderstood your own intention, or we have `audit_session_id` in other table too?

Comment: Thanks I understand but can't see how I get the data I need.  What I need to do is return a list of assets that haven't been audited for a given location and audit session.  In my head I can say take all the assets from auditedassets that have an audit session of X and all the assets from (table)assets that have location Y then remove all assets from the (table) assets list that appear in the auditedassets list and I have my answer.  However I don't know how to do this in SQL.  I'm quite happy to accept that my tables are badly structured if thats the issue juts not sure how to proceed.

Comment: IMO, If your need is `return a list of assets that haven't been audited for a given location and audit session` then you could just simply INNER JOIN two table then check the condition of `location and audit session`: `WHERE a.location_id = 15 AND audit_session_id = 'Audit1'` (that's for have been audited, for haven't been audited change AND to OR and = to <>) ?

Comment: As someone who never uses outer joins, I find these "`RIGHT JOIN` considered dangerous" warnings hilarious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to put the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT a.asset_number 
FROM auditeditems ai 
     asset a LEFT JOIN
     auditeditems ai
     ON ai.asset_number = a.asset_number AND
        ai.audit_session_id = 'Audit1'
WHERE ai.asset_number IS NULL AND a.location_id = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a wonky join. Try:

```
select A1.*
from Asset A1
left join AuditedItems A2
  on A1.asset_number = A2.asset_number
where A1.location_id = 15
and A2.asset_number is null
```

Comment: Thanks for this so LEFT JOIN it is but I still cant see how I can only get results for a specific audit_session_id.  This query seems to match all data in audited_items not just ones for a specific audit_session_id.

Comment: @Lee Someone far smarter than me will be able to explain, I just know that Right behaves weird in mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN` to find the specific assets audited in the session and location you desire, then 'anti-join' (e.g. using `NOT IN <table_epxression>`) to find all other assets:

```
SELECT asset_number 
  FROM asset
 WHERE asset_number NOT IN ( SELECT asset_number
                               FROM asset
                                    NATURAL JOIN
                                    auditeditems
                              WHERE audit_session_id = 'Audit1'
                                    AND location_id = 15 );
```